# How to check if div .has() 2 elements which are at the same level within the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've a bit of a challenge with jQuery...

I want to check if a wrapper div contains 2 specific elements, each with a specific class, so I can hide the wrapper **div.basic-question** and the **div.clearfix** right in front of it. But how can I get that to work?

I know of the .has() method but I can't get it to work in my desired use case with the 2 criteria being on the same level instead of being nested.

The sections I want to hide must contain both **div.basic-answers-for-slider** and **ul.basic-answers-results** which, as mentioned above, are both on the same level...

Here is the simplified html structure:

```
/* FIRST POLL, answered and showing results */
/* this div-section needs to remain visible */
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">      
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>    
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

/* these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code */
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question"> 
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div> 
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

/* these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code */
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question"> 
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div> 
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

/* SECOND POLL, not yet answered so no results visible yet */
/* this div-section needs to remain visible */
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">      
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>    
</div>

/* these 2 div-section needs to remain visible as there is no ul.basic-answers-results */
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question"> 
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div> 
</div>
```

My simple brain would say that I'd need to do something like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('div.basic-question').has('div.basic-answers-for-slider') ** && has('ul.basic-answers-results') ** .hide();
  $('div.basic-question').has('div.basic-answers-for-slider') ** && has('ul.basic-answers-results') ** .prev('div.clearfix').hide();
});
```

But that part between the **'s is obviously not going to work... and I seem to be unable to find the right hint online.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the approach I should take to get this working for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this using `.find().length`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".basic-question").find("div.basic-answers-for-slider").length > 0 && $(".basic-question").find("ul.basic-answers-results").length > 0) {
    console.log("yes")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g53wfx6p/

Comment: Thank you for the edit to my answer, but because I explain my answers in the code the code has to be visible, otherwise it just boils down to two sentences that imply there might be something to see.

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica it's just they make the page too long, usually when there's so much code I hide the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I can think of to do this is as below:

```js
// here we select `ul.basic-answers-results` that is an
// adjacent-sibling of the `div.basic-answers-for-slider
// element both of which are the immediate children of a
// `.basic-question` element:
$('.basic-question > div.basic-answers-for-slider + ul.basic-answers-results')
  // we then navigate from the child (`ul.basic-answers-results`)
  // element back to the parent, using the `parent()` method:
  .parent()
  // and then we add a class-name - here 'hide' - which is
  // used to hide the element (in the demo this adjusts
  // opacity to 0.2, to demonstrate how it works, but in
  // production this could be adjusted to `display: none;`:
  .addClass('hide');
```

```css
/* almost none of the CSS is relevant to the demo, and
   and is just for some aesthetics: */
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Calibri, Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
ul,
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 80%;
}

/* Not relevant to the demo, but here we use the :is()
   CSS psuedo-class function to shorten as an alternative
   to:
   .basic-question div::before,
   .basic-question ul::before */
.basic-question :is(div, ul)::before {
  content: attr(class);
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  border: 0 none transparent;
}

code {
  background-color: #cca;
  font-family: mono;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}

/* the utility class used to hide the element(s),
   for proof-of-concept I reduced the opacity,
   but "display: none;" could easily be substituted: */
.hide {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="problem-description">The sections I want to hide must contain both <code>div.basic-answers-for-slider</code> and <code>ul.basic-answers-results</code></p>
<!-- FIRST POLL, answered and showing results
     this div-section needs to remain visible -->
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND POLL, not yet answered so no results visible yet
     this div-section needs to remain visible  -->
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to remain visible as there is no
     ul.basic-answers-results -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
</div>
```

Of course, anything done with jQuery can also be achieved with plain JavaScript:

```js
// here we use document.querySelectorAll() to retrieve a NodeList
// of - as before - the `ul.basic-answers-results` elements which
// are the siblings of `div.basic-answers-for-slider` elements,
// both of which are the immediate child elements of a `.basic-question`
// element:
document.querySelectorAll(
  '.basic-question > div.basic-answers-for-slider + ul.basic-answers-results'
  // we then use NodeList.prototype.forEach() to iterate over each node in the
  // set returned by document.querySelectorAll():
).forEach(
  // using an Arrow function (since we don't need to use 'this'), to pass
  // the current Node (el) of the NodeList over which we're iterating
  // into the function, in which we navigate to the element's parentNode
  // and add the class 'hide' to handle the hiding:
  (el) => el.parentNode.classList.add('hide')
);
```

```css
/* almost none of the CSS is relevant to the demo, and
   and is just for some aesthetics: */

*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Calibri, Ubuntu, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div,
ul,
p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0.5em auto;
  width: 80%;
}


/* Not relevant to the demo, but here we use the :is()
   CSS psuedo-class function to shorten as an alternative
   to:
   .basic-question div::before,
   .basic-question ul::before */

.basic-question :is(div, ul)::before {
  content: attr(class);
  font-style: italic;
}

p {
  border: 0 none transparent;
}

code {
  background-color: #cca;
  font-family: mono;
  padding: 0 0.3em;
}


/* the utility class used to hide the element(s),
   for proof-of-concept I reduced the opacity,
   but "display: none;" could easily be substituted: */

.hide {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<p class="problem-description">The sections I want to hide must contain both <code>div.basic-answers-for-slider</code> and <code>ul.basic-answers-results</code></p>
<!-- FIRST POLL, answered and showing results
     this div-section needs to remain visible -->
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to be HIDDEN by the jQuery code -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
  <ul class="basic-answers-results basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- SECOND POLL, not yet answered so no results visible yet
     this div-section needs to remain visible  -->
<div class="basic-question basic-question-text-vertical">
  <ul class="basic-answers"></ul>
</div>

<!-- these 2 div-section needs to remain visible as there is no
     ul.basic-answers-results -->
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="basic-question">
  <div class="basic-answers-for-slider"></div>
</div>
```

References:

- CSS:

  - [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is).
- JavaScript:

  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).
  - [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addClass).
  - [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent).

Comment: Nice one, thanks. I'll have a closer look tonight as I do still have some hurdles with going to and from the results before a vote has been submitted. It's not the biggest issue as I can also reload the page after the 'back to vote' button has been clicked but perhaps your solution works even in that scenario. That all said, Alexandre Elshobokshy's solution (in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g53wfx6p/) works nicely as well.